# Unity game suddenly dropped to 0 fps causing the application to freeze after the application was running for a while

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm making an online game on unity, RPG game type
My game has an average FPS of about 60fps. After playing for a while, the game suddenly dropped in fps
This period can be 15p, 1 hour, 4 hours, ... it's not fixed but random
I checked the code and it's definitely not an endless loop
I used the profiler to check and found that when the game drops fps, the render time is very long, you can see that Semaphore.WaitForSignal has a very long wait time, this causes the game to drop fps.
Can you help me why the game crashes fps?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsQdw.png)

Comment: This usually means your app is GPU bound meaning the CPU is waiting for the GPU to finish rendering/a heavy job ... check your work load on the GPU .. do you e.g. use some compute shader? or maybe have a lot of drawcalls? or in general rendering something very intense (lots of verts/faces, complex shaders/effects etc)?

Comment: Is Auto Graphics API enabled in project settings ?

Comment: Yes Auto Graphics API is enable. Do you have any ideas

Comment: What version of unity are you using

Comment: I am using unity 2020.3.31f1 version. Pls help me pro

Comment: Is auto Connect profiler is enabled on build settings if yes try disabling it if not try updating your graphics driver also as derHugo said the issue is not related to your code but rather to the GPU